# Is there a way to have a table with values that references the columns themselves of another table?

Tags: mysql, relational-database, database-schema, entity-attribute-value

I have a database where data about users is stored in a table that looks like this

```
|_firstname_|_lastname_|_age_|...
|   John    | Johnson  |  21 |...
...
```

i.e. using the normal relational database model.

If I instead switched to an EAV model for storing the above data, the columns (called attributes in EAV) themselves would be stored in a table and would have unique column (attribute) ID:s. The benefit of this is that I could use these ID:s in another table to connect data to the columns *themselves*, such as whether the column is hidden or showed in the user UI (below also using an EAV model):

```
|____column_id____|___attribute___|___value___|
| <firstname_id>  |    hidden     |   false   |
| <lastname_id>   |    hidden     |   false   |
|    <age_id>     |    hidden     |   true    |
...
```

However, I would like to stick to the relational database model for the user data table (the table shown first), since querying otherwise becomes a lot slower, but I would still like to connect values to the columns like I can if I were to use an EAV model.

Is there a way of having a table that stores data about the columns themselves of the user data table in a rigorous way?

Comment: Do you plan to use your database by pure mysql or you will be interrogating it by another language php, java...?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest implementation of EAV may have just three tables: entity, attribute and value. An example of this setup is shown here:

[image: screenshot of EAV showing three tables: entity, attribute and value]

and so your table could look like :

```
|attribute_id| name       | is visible |
|10          | firstname  | 1          |
|11          | lastname   | 1          |
|12          | age        | 0          |

|entity_id  | entity_name |...
|1          | person1     |
|2          | person2     |

|row_id |attribute_id| entity_id | entity_id  |
|155    |10          | 1         | John       |
|156    |11          | 1         | Doe        |
|199    |12          | 1         | 28         |
|....    ....         ....        ....
|255    |10          | 2         | Ali        |
|256    |11          | 2         | Smith      |
|279    |12          | 2         | 25         |
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I'm afraid you must have misunderstood my question. I know how to switch to an EAV model for storing the user data, but I don't want to do this as this makes querying very slow. My question is whether there is a way of storing "properties" (such as the hidden: true/false property) of columns in another table if I use the relational database model.

Comment: Yes, I can see the difference after you edited the question, it's more clear now...